# Use Arrow Keys as Event Listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to allow users to use the arrow keys to move around between cells in an html table.  I would like to use jQuery to do this and would assume I need to make an event listener for each key and then somehow use parent/child to move focus between `td`.  I am currently using `contenteditable` to make the `td` cells editable so each time the user moves the previous `td` would `$(this).prop('contenteditable', false)` and the new `td` would become `$(this).prop('contenteditable', true)`

**My Question:**  I am looking for direction on how to set up these event listeners.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var old;
            
    $('td').click(function(){
                
        old=$(this).text();
                
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
                
                
    });
            
    var saveTimeout;
            
    // Remove the "saved" class on keydown
    $('td').on('keydown', function(e) {
        $(this).removeClass("saved");
    });
    
    $('td').on('input blur', function(e) {
                                
        var timeoutDelay=2500;
               
        if( e.type == "blur"){
            timeoutDelay=1;
        }
                
        // If NOT already saved...
        if( !$(this).hasClass("saved") ){
            var _this = $(this); // preserve reference to the input field here
            
            // Add the "saved" class to prevent other saving
            _this.addClass("saved");
            
            clearTimeout(saveTimeout);
            saveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(_this)
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "updatedatabase.php",
                    data: { 
                        content: _this.text(), 
                        date: _this.siblings().first().text(),
                        prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + (_this.index() + 1) + ')').text(),
                        old: old
                    }
                })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    alert( msg );
                });

                toastr.options = {
                    "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
                    "onclick": null,
                    "timeOut": "2500",
                }

                toastr.info(old,'Database Updated!<br><br>Your Previous Amount Was:');
                        
                _this.prop('contenteditable', false);
                        
            }, timeoutDelay);
        }
    });
            
            
    $("td").hover(function(){
                                
                
                    
        $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().first().addClass('highlight');

        $('tr:eq(1) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').addClass('highlight');
                
                
    },function(){
                
                
                    
        $(this).removeClass("highlight").siblings().first().removeClass('highlight');

        $('tr:eq(1) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').removeClass('highlight');
                
                
    });
    
});
```

```css
table,th, td {
  
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
        
}

.highlight {
    
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th>1234567</th>
    <th>7654321</th>
    <th>5678945</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th><u>22 ounce Dark</u></th>
    <th><u>12count 4oz Dark</u></th>
    <th><u>24count 6oz TJ</u></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-03</th>
    <td>13587</td>
    <td>2203</td>
    <td>4111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-04</th>
    <td>14111</td>
    <td>3247</td>
    <td>4332</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-05</th>
    <td>13212</td>
    <td>3101</td>
    <td>3911</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-06</th>
    <td>16335</td>
    <td>3299</td>
    <td>4001</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-07</th>
    <td>15421</td>
    <td>3100</td>
    <td>4078</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so attach the key events to the document and check for the key. But you know people use arrow keys to move around when they are editing text so have fun with that test case.

Comment: A quick search of this site should show you how to setup the event listeners, then use the element with focus, work out the element you're moving to based on which key was pressed and set the new focus. I'm not sure which bit of the problem you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (code == '38') {
        // Up
    }
    else if (code == '40') {
        // Down
    }
    else if (code == '37') {
       // Left
    }
    else if (code == '39') {
       // Right
    }
})
```

To get cell index you can do:

```
var cell_x = cell.cellIndex
var cell_y = cell.parentElement.rowIndex
```

Comment: [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated

Comment: @Andreas ho yeah ? Didn't know that. what's the new way to get key ?

Comment: Follow the link ;)

Comment: Interesting, it's not really deprecated, but FF handle that in other (new?) way

Comment: This will disrupt the behavior of the arrow keys where you may not want it. For example, scrolling the page, moving the cursor, it may be fine for very specific contexts, but it's a poor approach to follow unless you have done a lot of homework.

Comment: @JuanMendes, I agree, binding event on arrow keys isn''t the best. But if you didn't `preventDefault` event both will be done.

Comment: @Arthur That's true, but you do want to `preventDefault` if you make it move a cell, you probably don't want it to move the cell and also scroll the page. My suggestion? Check `event.target`, and ignore the handler if it's `document.body` or if it's an `input`, `select`. Not foolproof yet, but slightly better. Even better, don't set a document wide key handler, set it only on the element you want to catch the events, it may require adding tabindex to that element.